# how to add opaque types to collections

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, collections

How can I add an opaque type to a collection in cocoa?

I get a compiler warning for this (obviously, because opaque types are not objects):

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:colorSpace];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreFoundation data types (CFTypes) can be directly added to collections. (They need to be cast to (id) to suppress warnings.) This is called "toll free bridging."

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)colorSpace];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NSValue class to wrap your opaque types in an object. From [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An NSValue object is a simple
>   container for a single C or
>   Objective-C data item. It can hold any
>   of the scalar types such as int,
>   float, and char, as well as pointers,
>   structures, and object ids. The
>   purpose of this class is to allow
>   items of such data types to be added
>   to collections such as instances of
>   NSArray and NSSet, which require their
>   elements to be objects. NSValue
>   objects are always immutable.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. CFTypes can be directly added to collections through toll free bridging. See accepted answer.